# Hook in to plugin service call

Tags: grails

I have a plugin that executes a service call as a background process.  That is, it does some action on a timer that is not related directly to any user action.

What I need to do is execute some code in the "main" application every time this service call finishes.  Is there a way to hook into that plugin code?  I have access to the plugin code, so altering it isn't a huge obstacle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your plugin service publish an event when it completes then listen for that event in your main application.  I have used this pattern a few times and it has been a very convenient way to decouple various pieces of of my application.  To do this, create an [event](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html) class.

```
class PluginEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
   public PluginEvent(source) {
      super(source)
   }
}
```

Then, have your plugin service implement `ApplicationContextAware`.  That gives your plugin a way to publish your events

```
class PluginService implements ApplicationContextAware {
  def applicationContext

  def serviceMethod() {
     //do stuff
     publishPluginEvent()  
  }

  private void publishPluginEvent() {
    def event = new PluginEvent(this)
    applicationContext.publishEvent(event)
  }
}
```

Then in your main application, create a listener service that will respond when the event is published:

```
class ApplicationService implements ApplicationListener<PluginEvent> {
   void onApplicationEvent(PluginEvent event) {
     //whatever you want to do in your app when 
     // the plugin service fires.
   }
}
```

This listener doesn't need to be a Grails Service, you can just use a POJO/POGO, but you'll need to configure it as a spring bean inside `resources.groovy`.

I have been using this approach recently and it has worked well for me.  It's definitely a nice tool to have in your Grails toolbox.

Comment: Does the service need to be instantiated somehow then?

Comment: Not if it's a Grails service.  It will be initialized just like any other Grails service/Spring bean.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but it's all crickets unless I instantiate applicationService in Bootstrap.groovy.  Then it comes alive.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I didn't run into that problem, but you could try explicitly defining a spring bean for your service.  Or, maybe just add a `def applicationService` in your BootStrap so you don't have to instantiate it explicitly.